# Python API to know the location

Tags: python

Is there an Python API from which if we  input the ipadress, will we be able to know the location and place of the access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [MaxMind python API](http://www.maxmind.com/app/python)

Answer (score 0):

GeoDjango looks like it will suit your needs. I'm not sure exactly how you would want to direct users, but using the GeoIP API, you can do something like:

```
from django.contrib.gis.utils import GeoIP

g = GeoIP()

ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR', None)

if ip:

    city = g.city(ip)['city']

print "ip:",ip," city:",city
```

The Docs explain things in great detail (http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/); I would take a moment to read through them thoroughly